# What is the best way to return 1 if value is 0 and return value if value is larger than 0

Tags: ruby

As we knew, `0 || 1 = 0`

I want to do (always `value >= 0`)

```
if value == 0 return 1
elsif value > 0 return value
```

So best way is this?

`value = value > 0 ? value : 1`

Comment: Nothing to do with [tag:ruby-on-rails], this is a question for [tag:ruby]. Since you're just assigning back to `value`, you are doing one extra assignment; the best way in this context is `value = 1 if value.zero?` But that is a subjective answer (which is what typically happens with "what is best" questions), so the question will likely be closed.

Comment: do you want to more shorten syntax? or ruby-like way?

Comment: What's the expected result if value is less than 0?

Comment: @codermouse : What do you want if `value` is `nil`?

Comment: value will be always >= 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As we knew, `0 || 1 = 0`

To treat `0` as *falsey* use [`nonzero?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Numeric.html#method-i-nonzero-3F):

```
value.nonzero? || 1
```

The above returns `1` if `value` is 0, and `value` otherwise.

Comment: I like this, especially that it works for negative numbers too. I am slightly baffled by the fact the `nonzero?` returns the value rather than a Boolean though.

Comment: Questionmark methods can best thought of as returning a truthy or falsy value and not specifically `true` or `false`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r so, like all methods then?

Comment: @simonwo many methods will never return a falsey value, e.g. `to_i` always returns an integer, `to_s` always returns a string and so on. But I agree that it's odd in this  case. If I ask _"value, are you non-zero?"_, I don't expect _"five"_ as an answer. IMO, `nonzero` (without `?`) would have been a better method name.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you only ever deal with positive numbers, why not just:

```
[1, value].max
```

Comment: This was the BEST answer for my use case dealing with unsigned numbers only.